# Как c помощью css сделать картинки одного размера?

Tags: html, css

Может кто-нибудь помочь.Каждое изображение 261px на 261px. Второе фото меньше. Как при помощи css сделать все фото одного размера?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.customers-wrap {
    margin-bottom: 90px;
}
.customers-wrap::after {
    content: '';
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
.customers-block {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
}
.customers-img {
    width: 261px;
    height: 261px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    float: left; 
}
```

```html
<div class="customers-wrap">
 <div class="customers-block">
  <div class="customers-img">
   <img src="img/customers/img-1.png" alt="img-1">
   </div>
   <!-- /.customers-img -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.customers-block -->
                    
  <div class="customers-block">
   <div class="customers-img">
    <img src="img/customers/02.png" alt="img-2">
   </div>
   <!-- /.customers-img -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.customers-block -->

  <div class="customers-block">
   <div class="customers-img">
    <img src="img/customers/img-3.png" alt="img-3">
   </div>
   <!-- /.customers-img -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.customers-block -->

  <div class="customers-block">
   <div class="customers-img">
    <img src="img/customers/img-4.png" alt="img-4">
   </div>
   <!-- /.customers-img -->
   </div>
   <!-- /.customers-block -->
   <!-- /.customers-wrap -->
```

Comment: Не  советую. Фото расширится, будет выглядеть, мягко говоря, хреново...

Comment: А вообще можно его задать фоном и применить `background-size:cover;`

Comment: Я понимаю, но может подскажете как это можно сделать?

Comment: попробую background-size:cover как вы сказали

Comment: Я же подсказал в комментарии втором.

Comment: Кстати, чтобы второе фото не слишком выделялось, можно остальные чуть-чуть сузить а второе расширить

Comment: не получается как вы сказали, может для второго фото прописать в html tyle="width: 261px; height: 286px;

Comment: Лучше покажи свой код

Comment: Попробуйте в `.customers-img` добавить `object-fit:cover`.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.filters__img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 10px;
}

.filters__img img {
  width: initial;
  height: 100%;
}

.box{
display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="filters__img"><img src="https://img1.goodfon.ru/wallpaper/big/1/ca/foto-makro-kartinka-zelenye.jpg" alt="1"></div>
  <div class="filters__img"><img src="https://img1.goodfon.ru/wallpaper/big/1/ca/foto-makro-kartinka-zelenye.jpg" alt="1"></div>
  <div class="filters__img"><img src="https://img1.goodfon.ru/wallpaper/big/1/ca/foto-makro-kartinka-zelenye.jpg" alt="1"></div>
  <div class="filters__img"><img src="https://img1.goodfon.ru/wallpaper/big/1/ca/foto-makro-kartinka-zelenye.jpg" alt="1"></div>
  <div>
```

Если я Вас правильно понял

Answer (score 1):

```css
.customers-img {
    float:left;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    width:261px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    float:left;
    height:250px;
}
```

Comment: Помогло  это  http://2web-master.ru/lab/image_crop/02.html#

Answer (score 0):

Хоть вопрос и старый, но стоящего ответа я не вижу.

Насколько я понимаю, нужно заполнить картинкой всё пространство родителя, для этого есть замечательное свойство `object-fit`.

У него есть несколько значений, но мы воспользуемся `object-fit: cover`:

**cover**
Смещаемый контент меняет свой размер таким образом, чтобы сохранять свои пропорции при заполнении блока: окончательный размер контента будет определен как "покрытие" блока, ограничиваясь его шириной и высотой.
([источник](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit))

Всё внимание на `.block.object-fit img`:

```css
.block {
  display: block;
}

.block:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: -60px;
}

.block::before {
  display: block;
  font-size: 120%;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.block.no-object-fit::before {
  content: 'Без object-fit: cover';
}

.block.object-fit::before {
  content: 'object-fit: cover';
}

.block .image {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
}

.block.object-fit img {
  max-width: 100%; /* Максимальная ширина картинки */
  min-height: 100%; /* Минимальная высота картинки */
  object-fit: cover; /* Всю, выше указанную, облась заполнить картинкой */
}
```

```html
<div class="block no-object-fit">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/120x120">
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/120x60">
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/120x120">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="block object-fit">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/120x120">
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/120x60">
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/120x120">
  </div>
</div>
```